# android asynctask attempt

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement asynctask in a twitter oauth activity, but I get 2 errors. I would like the asynctask to return a consumer object.

Here's my code:

```
class getCommonsHttpConsumer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected OAuthConsumer doInBackground() {

    return new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
}
}
```

I get two errors

1. getCommonsHttpConsumer: The type getCommonsHttpConsumer must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask.doInBackground(Void...)
2. doInBackground(): The method doInBackground() of type getCommonsHttpConsumer must override or implement a supertype method

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If any of our answers helped, you should accept the best one. If not, you can always leave feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the docs of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), you'll see this:-

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Since, you've given your `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` as this, your

```
protected OAuthConsumer doInBackground()
```

is throwing those errors.

Change the return type of `doInBackground()` to either `Void` or the `AsyncTask` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, OAuthConsumer>` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Read what the compiler is telling you and also get familiar with the documentation. You need to change the parameterization on the class declaration to declare that doInBackground will return a `OAuthConsumer` Also have `doInBackground()` accept in `Void...` (varargs):

```
class getCommonsHttpConsumer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, OAuthConsumer> {

@Override 
protected OAuthConsumer doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

Also a good explanation (aside from the docs) can be found [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to do:

```
class getCommonsHttpConsumer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, OAuthConsumer> {

    @Override
    protected OAuthConsumer doInBackground() {

        return new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(OAuthConsumer result) {
        // process result
    }
}
```

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more detail.